# iOS - On clicking notification it does not redirect to respective page

Tags: ios, push-notification, ionic-framework

In IOS,
When app is removed from background and user obtain notification,by tap on that notification it is not triggering

**function**
$rootScope.push.on('notification', function (data) {  });

If app running in background, then by tap of notification it is triggering this function.
Is there any other way to trigger this function when app is not running in background in ios.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know in ionic, but in iOS

you will have to handle this in iOS as below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *pushInfo = launchOptions[ UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:pushInfo];
}
```

Comment: We have tried this way through holding value and returning through app side after app launches but by clearing it immeditely it is not returning data to app side.If we clear through setting timer then from sencond time onwards it is not returning data.It is working only for first time of returning data to app side after app launches.